# HQL query to get all name from a table

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a **StudentInfo** table, I need to fetch all the **names** under **name** column in the table.

can any one help me to correct me in the below function

```
 @Override
 public List<StudentRecord> getAllStudentNames(){

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

     try {

        List<StudentRecord> smrList = new ArrayList<StudentRecord>();

            String SQL_QUERY = "select smr.studentName from StudentRecord as smr";
        Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY)  

         smrList  = query.list();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
            HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
        }


        return smrList  
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want names, and names are strings, so you don't want a `List<StudentRecord>`, but a `List<String>`.

The `query.list()` method returns a List, so there's no need to create a new ArrayList, only to replace it by the list returned by the method.

So you just need the following (which respects Java naming conventions):

```
String hql = "select smr.studentName from StudentRecord as smr";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);  
List<String> result = query.list();
return result;
```

Note that I named the variable `hql`, and not `sql`, since HQL and SQL are not the same language, and you're using HQL here. The above query will work if the persistent property of the `StudentRecord` class is named `studentName`. The name of the table and the name of the column are irrelevant, since HQL uses entities for its queries, and not tables.

Finally, you should not catch Exception: it will only hide errors. Let the exception propagate to the caller.

It seems you lack basic Java knowledge. I would start by learning Java with simpler problems before using Hibernate, which is a complex framework.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is correct, you are using `select query and select query always return list of object array if more than one column is define in the query` `or list of a selected column type` 
so you just need to do the below with your code and will work fine.

```
List<Object[]> objList = query.list();    
return objList ;
```

now you will get all the names, iterate the `objList` and set them to your smrList

or

```
List<String> nameList = query.list();
return nameList;
```

Comment: You're wrong. A query returning a single property as above will return a `List<String>`. It returns a `List<Object[]>` only if you select multiple things: `select student.name, student.age ...`

Comment: And your first code snippet is still wrong, and it creates a new ArrayList for nothing.